# "Failed to load map" error contacting Google servers

Tags: android, google-maps

I have checked all the threads about this topic but even following the advices and tutorials I have the same problem.

The strange thing is that I have created a sample project with the same configuration and **it works**! And it works even if I change the api key so I don't know if the problem is the key or not.

Manifest file:

```
<permission
    android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Inside application tag:

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="my api key"/>
```

Activity:

```
 public class MapaActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private GoogleMap mMap; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mapa);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {            
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40, 12)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is the api key i guess. have you enabled maps for android in the api console?

Comment: yes, Google Maps Android API v2 activated

Answer (score 0):

are you running both apps with same keystore?
api key should be created along with sha1 fingerprint and package name so you might missed some logic.

Comment: I have generated many keys with different accounts, all of them work in one app but none of them work in the other